# What does "Data and ISV Applications" and "Operating system" mean in SLES 12 roles during install?

Tags: system-installation, sles

We are installing SLES12, via GUI installer and wondering, what is behind the ROLE, when creating ex.: logical volumes:

- Operating system
- Data and ISV Applications

We can see that maybe "/" should use the first one, "/home" the second, but what exactly is the difference in the two? Different mount options or FS settings or what?

Comment: at least, can someone point out the source code? cannot find it via Google. From the source code we could maybe see that what is exactly behind this two definition.

Answer (score 1):

It changes the defaults for the later menus.

From https://github.com/yast/yast-storage-ng/blob/master/doc/user-stories/expert-partitioner.md

If partition role is 'Operating system'

```
sets the following 'Formatting options' by default
    Format partition: true
        File System: Btrfs
        Enable snapshots: true
    Do not format partition: false
        File System Id: 0x83 Linux
    Encrypt: false
sets the following options for 'Mounting options'
    Mount partition: true
        Mount point: first free of /, /home, /var
    Do not mount partition: false
```

If partition role is 'Data and ISV applications'

```
sets the following 'Formatting options' by default
    Format partition: true
        File System: XFS
    Do not format partition: false
        File System Id: 0x83 Linux
    Encrypt: false
sets the following options for 'Mounting options'
    Mount partition: true
        Mount point: first free of /, /home, /var
    Do not mount partition: false
```